# Does Expo EAS build command update previously released app?

Tags: react-native, expo, app-store, eas

I have built production app with EAS Build and published to app stores.

Build versions uses channel `production` which is linked to branch `production`

I want to build new version, download it and publish via store in "traditional way" so I build new production app on channel `production`.

What will happen with the app already installed on users devices? Will expo build add new update to branch `production` so users will download the update just after build finishes?

Or old app version will not receive an update and new version will be available only after app store review?

Thanks for clarify!

Edit:
As I found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/how-eas-update-works/#matching-updates-and-builds) it depends on runtime version. If the same runtime version is specified, update will be applied to installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

Running `eas build` will **not** automatically publish any code updates to existing apps already running on users' devices, even if they are the same channel and runtime version.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#no-more-automatic-publishing-before-building